# Qrcode.js - Error: code length overflow. (1716>1056)

Tags: javascript, qr-code

I am using http://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/ to generate a QR Code for an event, but when I try to make code from a string shown below I get this error **Error: code length overflow. (1716>1056)**. I found out that when I change `correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H` to the medium it works. It also works when I remove DESCRIPTION or some other part of the string.

Can you explain to me how the limits work, and how should I set so when the code is generated from the user's input (it can have really long description) it won't crash?

```
qrkod(){
  this.qrCodeText =    "BEGIN:VCALENDAR"+"%0D%0A"+
                       "VERSION:1.0"+"%0D%0A"+
                       "BEGIN:VEVENT"+"%0D%0A"+
                       "DTSTART:" + "19960401T090000" +"%0D%0A"+
                       "DTEND:" + "19960401T043000" +"%0D%0A"+
                       "SUMMARY:" + "Your Proposal Review"+"%0D%0A"+
                       "DESCRIPTION:" + "Steve and John to review newest proposal material"+"%0D%0A"+
                       "END:VEVENT"+"%0D%0A"+
                       "END:VCALENDAR"+"%0D%0A";
  this.qrCodeText = decodeURIComponent(this.qrCodeText);

  this.qrcode0 = new QRCode("qrcode", {
      text: this.qrCodeText,
      width: 363,
      height: 385,
      colorDark : "#000000",
      colorLight : "#ffffff",
      correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
  });
}
```

Comment: The correction level (ECC level) determines the capacity of the QR code. Check [this](http://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html). When you have user input, you need to make sure the overall length of the text is within these bounds. Check if you can increase the capacity by zip-ing the text before passing it to `QRCode`, e.g. using the [JSZip library](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/).

Comment: @miraculixx why do I have to zip it? The string that I showed in the example is not that long but it crashes. Why ?

Comment: you don't _have_ to zip it, but when you do the text may have less bytes so you can store more content. First and foremost, make sure you stay within the maximum size of the ECC level you choose. QR codes have a maximum capacity, it is not a magic box that can store any length of content.

Comment: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntcbC.png) The "typeNumber" is the version number (1-40)and the "errorCorrectionLevel" is the level of correction that indicate the % of restoration from total codes. I don't get it very good, but you can see this page[caracteristicas QR](https://www.qrcode.com/en/about/version.html). To me been util. The image is the [documentation qrcode.js](https://github.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator/tree/master/js).

Answer (score 10):

I have hit this same error myself using the library, it appears there is a bug in the library where if you use CorrectLevel.H and have a string between 192 and 220 character it will fail (Note that the length specified in the error message is not the same as the length of the string). It doesn't allocate the correct number of space/blocks for the QR code and then catches that error.

This can be resolved by either increasing/decreasing the string length to be outside of that range.

Comment: if you check the error provided it says:
__Error: code length overflow. (1716>1056)__
which means that the string is __1716__ and the max accepted length is __1056__.
so he's already out of the range you provided.

Comment: If you url decode qrCodeText in his example it is 212 characters long which was in the range that I was experiencing the exact same issue. The code length overflow error doesn't refer to the length of the string passed into the QRCode constructor.

Comment: sorry, you're correct, can you please edit your answer so I can remove the down vote.

Comment: where can i increase the string?

Comment: Error occured for me with range (192 <= length <= 217) , I add some space to make sure always my string length is more than 217

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue for me too. For me extra spaces at end didn't matter so I appended spaces using `qrCodeText = qrCodeText.padEnd(220);`

Answer (score 3):

As sugested by [Archit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661195/archit-jain) in [a comment on the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796584/qrcode-js-error-code-length-overflow-17161056/73544657#comment123108831_34890253), doing this fixed my problem:

```
qrCodeText = qrCodeText.padEnd(220);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite simple to resolve.

```js
 var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
        correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.L
 });
```

Use:

```
correctLevel : QRCode.CorrectLevel.L
```

Comment: This is work for me!

Answer (score 1):

You will only get this error when your using minified version of cdn try using other than minified one it will work [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/qrcodejs)